# TortoiseGit integration with PL/SQL Developer

Tags: plsqldeveloper, tortoisegit

Does anyone know if it's possible to integrate TortoiseGit on windows with PL/SQL Developer, and if so, how please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have used TortoiseHg as VCS in several SQL-related projects using PL/SQL Developer as editor. As with TortoiseGit it's a shell extension with the same ancestry.

I tried hard to make Tools (buttons and menu elements) in the Tools menu, such as commit, push and pull that used Hg command calls. But in the end it was just inferior to using Hg from the command line or Explorer.

But in any case you'll want to try it; open Tools Configuration from the Tools menu. Click the icon for a new Tool and give it a descriptive description as Git Pull, type External, point to the git executable  as Parameter it should be sufficient with "pull" and default path should probably be "#dir" which would be the directory of the file in the current window.

This Tool may now be used as a menu element or used as a button in the toolbar.

Comment: Hi Oey, this is a great way to do it.  I'd never thought about creating custom tools myself for pl/sql developer.  I have created tools that point to TortoiseGitProc.exe with different parameters for pull, commit, etc.  Thank you ever so much for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseGit is a shell extension, it only integrates into Explorer.exe and other tools which use the context menu or the file listing of it.

Comment: I see, so instead I should be looking for a standard git plugin for the development environment. Thanks :)